# Regarding class level lock

Tags: java, multithreading

At a Java interview it was asked with a context to threads that there is a class ABC consists of two static synchronized methods  `m1()` and `m2()`, and there is two threads `T1`, `T2`, if `T1` takes a lock on method `m1()` then at the same time is it possible for `T2` to take lock on `m2()` method, I replied that since `m1()` and `m2()` are static synchronized so they are having class level lock so if `T1` thread takes the lock on `m1()` method then no other thread could take a lock on `m1()` at the same time until `T1` releases the lock from `m1()` method but at the same time thread `T2` can take lock on method `m2()`, please advise it is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One doesn't acquire locks on *methods* in Java, but rather on *objects*. A synchronized static method implicitly uses the class object as the lock. Naturally, two methods in the same class will both contend for the same lock and will not be allowed to execute concurrently.

Comment: Thanks a lot perfect explnation , could you please advise for any example which shows this , so it will help to grasp more.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Wrong... a lock on a synchronized method blocks all other synchronized methods calls

Comment: so you mean to say if T1 thread takes a class level lock on static synchronized method m1() then at the same time thread T2 can not take lock on another static syncronized method m2() since Thread T1 has put class level lock on method m1().n could you please show a with a small example to grasp more. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes exactly... I cant give u a more datailed example than what u wrote. Just try to inplement it if u want and u'll see...